# Is it possible to open a large csv without loading it to RAM entirely

Tags: python, operating-system

Suppose I have a very large csv file.

`file = open("foo.csv")`

seems to put the whole csv in RAM. If I just need the first row of the csv but don't want python to load the open the entire file, is there a way to do it?

Comment: open does not place the whole file in memory. When you later call readline you will only read one line at a time.

Comment: @Fredrik how do you know this?

Comment: The documentation for the built-in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function explains that it returns a file object, which is defined in the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) as something with an API with methods such as `read()` — hardly the same thing as the entire contents of a file...

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the first row then you can use the csv module like so.

```py
import csv

with open("foo.csv", "r") as my_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(my_csv)

    first_row = next(reader)

# do stuff with first_row
```

The CSV module uses generators so the whole file is not loaded into RAM, more rows are loaded as requested to prevent the whole file being loaded into RAM.

Comment: Can I know what is generator?

Comment: My favorite overview of generators: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator   ... they feed you one line at a time, you get to decide what to do with it.